# Without Session Pass variable in another page using PHP

Tags: php

I have working some code.... Without session send another page in php...
Any one help me.

```
<?php
$forget=$_POST['forget'];
if(isset($forget))
{
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("tamil")or die(mysql_error());
  $query=mysql_query("select * from register where username='$forget' OR email='$forget'")or die(mysql_error());
  if(mysql_num_rows($query)== 1)
  {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
        header('Location: new_password.php',$row);
        echo $row['username'];

  }
  else
  {
        echo "enter valid details";
  }

}
else
{
  echo "enter your name or mail";
}
?>
```

I will send **$row** variable in another page....
**header('Location: new_password.php',**$row **);**

Comment: Since when is the second parameter from `header()` an array ?

Comment: @Tamil: Please consider not to pass the POST-Vars directly to your SQL-Statement to avoid [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 0):

keeping the security measures at stake you can also urlencode and serialize the entire result send like this

```
 header('Location: new_password.php?row='.urlencode(serialize(($row)));
```

while ideally we just send user_id

```
header('Location: new_password.php?id='.$row['id']);
```